# Get loaded classes within ANOTHER JVM

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I'd like to be able to read data from a separate JVM (essentially "peek" into it) at will so I can read specific class instance values and/or invoke methods. I've looked into using both agents and the attach API but each of them seems to only be designed for runtime instrumentation and not being able to grab the actual instance itself.

Comment: Do you want to invoke any method that is available on the other JVM or only specific ones? In the latter case you can use [JMX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/).

Answer (score 0):

An instance of an object only exists in one JVM if you use managed memory.

If you use a data structure which uses shared memory, you can do this e.g. [Chronicle Map](http://chronicle.software/products/chronicle-map/)  This makes memory accessible to multiple JVMs, but only by using off heap, shared memory.

Comment: So pretty much what you're telling me is the only way to "sort of" accomplish what I'm talking about is loading a proxy class into the target JVM and communicating that way?

Comment: @Swizzbeat That is what the first line suggests this.  The second paragraph gives you an alternative.